# Reusing cells UICollectionView - some cells don't get selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

In the `UICollectionView`, I've got a custom `UICollectionViewCellClass`, where **prepareForReuse** is overridden for default formatting staff.

I've got an `NSMutableArray` containing `NSIndexPaths` from **didSelectItemAtIndexPath:**.

In **cellForItemAtIndexPath:** I reformat the selected cells so they appear selected.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

ButtonCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ButtonCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSString *title = self.ingredientsBook.names[indexPath.item];

cell.label.text = title;

if ([self isSelectedIndexPath:indexPath]){

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.label.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
return cell;

}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

self.searchButton.enabled = YES;

ButtonCell *cell = (ButtonCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[selectedCellIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
NSLog(@"%@", selectedCellIndexPaths);
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
cell.label.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];

NSString *name = self.ingredientsBook.names[indexPath.item];
[self.selectedIngredientNames addObject:name];


}
```

The problem is that when I tap the first cell it's not possible to select the 16th or 17th.
Or if I tap the first three ones it's not possible to select the three last ones.
The `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` is not being called I suppose.

I feel that it has to be something really simple but I can't see it right now.

I tried to put `NSLogs`in `shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath` for understand if that method was called and the method is not being called at all. This happens when there's a distance of 16 cells between the selected one and the problematic one.

Here are other data source methods and isSelectedIndexPath:

```
-(BOOL)isSelectedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

for (NSIndexPath *test in selectedCellIndexPaths){
    if (test == indexPath){
        return YES;
    }
}

return NO;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

return [self.ingredientsBook.names count];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{

return 1;
}

-(BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);

return YES;
}


-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

self.searchButton.enabled = ([[collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] count] > 0);

ButtonCell *cell = (ButtonCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
cell.label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

[selectedCellIndexPaths removeObject:indexPath];
NSString *name = self.ingredientsBook.names[indexPath.item];
[self.selectedIngredientNames removeObject:name];



}
```

Comment: What is isSelectedIndexPath? Where do you create that? I think you also need an "else" part to say what the cells should look like if [self isSelectedIndexPath:indexPath] returns false.

Comment: it is a method that checks if the indexPath is contained in the NSMutableArray of NSIndexPaths. it always return false apart when the indexPath is equal to one of the selected ones in the array.

Comment: Ok, did you add the "else" part to the if statement to see if that helps. Because of cell reuse, you need to set the cell's appearance to the unselected state if that if statement is false.

Comment: I can't explain the every 16th cell thing without seeing more code. I don't see anything in what you've posted that would explain that. You should post all the data source methods and the isSelectedIndexPath: method.

Comment: i tried adding the "else part" but it doesn't seem to be affected by that. when i log the shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath: i get no answer. as if the method hasn't been called. but i'm tapping that cell! it's crazy

Comment: i'm gonna try to post the whole project

Comment: here is the whole project https://github.com/aluphedrion/Tomatto

Comment: What do I need to do to test your error? I only see 6 cells, so I can't get to 16 or 17.

Comment: sorry it wasn't updated check again the git repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two problems. The prepareForReuse method seemed to be screwing things up, so I just deleted it. The main problem though, was the way you were implementing isSelectedIndexPath:. As soon as it finds the first selected item as you loop through the items, it returns YES and exits the loop. What you want to do, is just check if the indexPath is contained in the selectedCellIndexPaths array:

```
-(BOOL)isSelectedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if ([selectedCellIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath]) {
        return YES;
    }else{
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Or, if you prefer to use a more succinct syntax, you can replace the if-else block with:

```
return  ([selectedCellIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath])? YES : NO;
```

Comment: even with these changes the problem persist. however thanks a lot for your patience and persistence.

Comment: sorry, i miss to delete prepareForReuse. Now everything works brilliant. thanx a lot for patience and persistence again.

Comment: Just: `return [selectedCellIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath];`

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced the exact same issue with my app. UICollectionViewCell selection worked properly prior to iOS 8.3, subsequently I started to see some strange behaviour. Cells that were not actually selected would appear selected, other cells, seemingly at random could not be selected.

I had both custom `setSelected` and  `prepareForResuse` methods implemented on a UICollectionViewCell subclass as such:

```
 -(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected
{
     [super setSelected:selected];

    if (selected)
    {
        [[self selectedIndicator] setHidden:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        [[self selectedIndicator] setHidden:YES];
    }
}

-(void)prepareForReuse
{
    [[self imageView] setImage:nil];
}
```

The `prepareForReuse` method simply reset an image view in the custom cell.

In my `prepareForReuse` method I did not make a call to `[super prepareForReuse]` (which according to the documentation does nothing by default). When I added the call to `[super prepareForReuse]` all selection worked as intended. Although Apple states the default implementation does nothing, they also recommend that super should be called. Following this recommendation solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 10 I found that programmatically clearing a UICollectionView that had multiple-selection enabled was buggy when prefetching was enabled. And of course prefetch is on by default in iOS 10.